# Remove unwanted characters from a string

Tags: c#, strings

From what I've seen in other posts, if I actually know the unwanted characters, then I can do `string.replace()`. But in my case, any characters can appear in my input string, and I only want to keep the characters that I want (without messing up the order of course).

```
private string RemoveUnwantedChar(string input)
{
    string correctString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(input[i]) || input[i] == '.' || input[i] == '-' || input[i] == 'n'
                || input[i] == 'u' || input[i] == 'm' || input[i] == 'k' || input[i] == 'M'
                || input[i] == 'G' || input[i] == 'H' || input[i] == 'z' || input[i] == 'V'
                || input[i] == 's' || input[i] == '%')
            correctString += input[i];
    }
    return correctString;
}
```

Characters that I want:

- 0123456789
- numkMGHzVs%-

How can I tidy this code to be neater and more readable?

Comment: Cross-posted with [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33474706/1014587), question has an accepted answer there.

Comment: Note that `IsDigit` accepts any unicode digit, not just the ASCII `0` to `9`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I am a bit confused, can you please elaborate on that? I thought `IsDigit` checks for 0-9, while `IsNumber` checks for even more, like subscripts and fractions?

Comment: @Liren There are digits besides 0-9. The full-width ０-９ and digits from various languages, e.g. ୫, ൬, ᠑

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- By having a `const string` which contains all of your wanted chars, you could do either a simple call to `Contains()` or check if `IndexOf()` will return a value `> -1`.
- using string concatenation in a loop is mostly a bad idea. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.
- omitting braces `{}` although they are optional for single lined `if` statements is a bad idea because it makes your code error prone.

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to

```
private const string allowedCharacters = "numkMGHzVs%-.";
private string RemoveUnwantedChar(string input)
{

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(input[i]) || allowedCharacters.Contains(input[i]))
        {
            builder.Append(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

@Caricorc made a good suggestion in the comments

> In my opinion `allowedCharacters` should be an argument to the function to allow reusability.

So by passing the `allowedCharacters` as an optional parameter with an additional check with `IsNullOrEmpty()`.

If performance is an issue, you could also pass a `HashSet<char>` to the method or have an overloaded method like so

```
private string RemoveUnwantedChar(string input, string allowedCharacters = "0123456789numkMGHzVs%-.")
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(allowedCharacters)) { return input; }

    return RemoveUnwantedChar(input, new HashSet<char>(allowedCharacters));

}  
private string RemoveUnwantedChar(string input, HashSet<char> allowedCharacters)
{
    if (allowedCharacters.Count == 0) { return input; }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (allowedCharacters.Contains(input[i]))
        {
            builder.Append(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

you can reuse it somewhere else.

Comment: In my opinion `allowedCharacters` should be an argument to the function to allow reusability.

Comment: I think `char.IsDigit(input[i]) ||` is a problem in the second function, as the user may or may not allow digits

Comment: Perfect :) , my last suggestion is converting the allowedchars to a set to reduce time complexity from n^2 to n. (Actually I should have posted all of this as an aswer but now it is too late to convert it)

Comment: I feel that `RemoveUnwantedCharacters` should have a `blacklist` parameter, not a `whitelist` parameter. This really should be `ConformToWhitelist` or something - we're not removing unwanted characters so much as we're keeping wanted characters. A subtle difference, but a difference nevertheless. I would assume `RemoveUnwantedCharacters` would ask me for characters I don't want!

Comment: @corsiKa very good point actually! I did feel the same way after that, I now changed my method name to `FilterString`.

Comment: So I should always avoid things like `correctString += input[i];` inside a loop? What is the benefits of using `builder.Append(input[i]);` instead? Should I always go for `StringBuilder` when playing around with strings?

Comment: If you are doing `correctString += input[i]` you are creating each time a new string because strings are immutable. The `StringBuilder` doesn't do this because it inernally uses an array of chars to store the chars of the passed string. And no, you shouldn't always use the `StringBuilder` but for sure if you do string concatenation in a loop.

Answer (score 11):

Whenever I see filtering, I tend to think LINQ.

```
private string RemoveUnwantedCharacters(string input, IEnumerable<char> allowedCharacters)
{
    var filtered = input.ToCharArray()
        .Where(c => allowedCharacters.Contains(c))
        .ToArray();

    return new String(filtered);
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
string filteredString = RemoveUnwantedCharacters(inputString, "0123456789numkMGHzVs%-.");
```

- Code is shorter
- The intent is clear - it basically reads as "filtered is input where allowed characters contains this character", which is pretty self-explanatory
- Allowed characters is a parameter, so you can reuse the method in various places. If you're using the same set of allowed characters in a lot of places, stick them in some sort of settings store.

Comment: Using `AsEnumerable` on the `input` would be even more `LINQ`-ish ;-)

Comment: True, but I tend to work with arrays when going back and forth between `string` and a bunch of `char`s. No real reason; mostly just because there's a specific `ToCharArray()` and out of left-over habits from other languages.

Comment: 1) A string is already an `IEnumerable<char>`. Both `AsEnumerable` and `ToCharArray` are useless here. 2) No need for a lambda. Just use `.Where(allowedCharacters.Contains)`

Comment: @CodesInChaos you're right, I just checked it in `VisualStudio`. My previous comment was based on `LINQPad` that didn't allow me to use `Where` without `AsEnumerable`, strange.

Comment: @t3chb0t It works in LINQPad for me. It's just the auto-completition that omits these extension methods.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I see I trusted LINQPad's intellisense too much ;-] I compiles and runs but doesn't show up as suggestion.

Comment: @CodesInChaos while `.Where(allowedCharacters.Contains)` works, it takes me much more mental effort to understand than  `.Where(c => allowedCharacters.Contains(c))`.  I think the increased clarity is well worth the 8 extra keypresses.

Comment: @CarlLeth - I think that's a personal preference thing; I much prefer the more concise version.

Comment: @CarlLeth can you please give me a quick explanation of difference between `.Where(c => allowedChars.Any(x => x == c))` and your `.Contains`?

Comment: @Liren same effect from opposite routes. The `.Contains()` is checking "does that collection contain this character" while the `.Any()` is checking "are any of the characters in this collection the same as this one". They end up doing the same thing, but you're doing with `.Where()` and `.Any()` is to manually do what `.Contains()` is actually *intended* for.

Comment: @Liren They're semantically equivalent.  `Contains` is more specific, which is nice both for readability and because implementations can make better assumptions than with the general `Any`.  For instance, I might expect EntityFramework to translate `Set.Contains(c)` into a SQL statement like `c in Set`, but `Set.Any(x => x == c)` into `exists (select null from Set where Set.Id = @0)`.  There may also be cases where `Contains` is constant time or O(log(n)) but `Any` is O(n).  These hypotheticals may not apply to your use case, but they are examples why I prefer more specific functions.

Answer (score 5):

Same answer as on SO

Whenever you have to search for literals. Regex is the way to go.

```
public string RemoveUnwantedChar(string input) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var match in Regex.Matches(input, "[0-9numkMGHzVs%\\-.]")) {
            stringBuilder.Append(match.ToString());
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

- Code is shorter
- Very easy to expand
- Easy to read
- Easy to follow the Code

Second Solution. A nice OneLiner as Taemyr suggested:

```
public string RemoveUnwantedChar(string input) {
        return Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9numkMGHzVs%\\-.]", "");
    }
```

// Edit from String concatenation to StringBuilder implementation for better Performace especially for large inputs

// Edit2 Escaped the Dash for more Info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.

Comment: String concatenation in a loop, while present in the original code, is an anti-pattern (negative impact on performance, possibly a problem for large inputs)

Comment: First; you need to escape the dash.  Second; your function body can be replaced with `return Regex.Replace(input,"[^0-9numkMGHzVs%\\-.]","")`

Comment: You can alternatively put the hyphen at the beginning or end of the character class.